.NET Core OIDC challenge redirect not working with an Angular frontend
I am trying to implement the token mediating backend/backend for frontend pattern (my frontend is Angular v18). I want my frontend to be dumb and not have any knowledge of handling tokens. I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that sets up the OIDC configuration like this:
//... other code removed for brevity
builder.Services.AddAuthentication.AddOpenIdConnect(
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    opts =>
    {
        opts.Authority = builder.Configuration["Authority"];
        opts.ClientId = builder.Configuration["ClientId"];
        opts.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["ClientSecret"];
        opts.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        opts.ResponseType = "code";
        opts.UsePkce = true;

        if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        }

        opts.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        opts.ClaimActions.MapAll();

    });

With the following middleware, that checks for a particular cookie, which if not present, initiates the challenge:
app.Use(
async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(AuthConstants.CookieSessionKey))
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
});

The entire flow works if I call an endpoint in my API directly from the browser, but NOT if I try to call it from my Angular app, for example:
this.http.get<UserSession>("https://localhost:7030/.well-known/bff-getsessioninfo")
    .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
    })

Instead, what happens is, the backend returns a 200 and Angular attempts to deserialize the response which it fails because it is the HTML of the IdP login page

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', " <!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse

My expected flow is:

Frontend attempts to get the user session info
Backend sees the unauthenticated request due to the absence of the session cookie.
Backend triggers the OIDC challenge
Redirect to the IdP to login
Redirect into my Backend with the access tokens
Send the user session info back to my angular frontend with the cookie set

Why does it not redirect correctly when being called from Angular?

Its an expected result, when you are using the http.get this is a build-n feature which will not redirect, you need analysis the result and then redirect to the page, normally, we will not do this thing inside the http.get method, we will check it when the user firstly access any page which will not facing this error inside the http.get method.

Seems that in order to know if the user is logged in or not, you need to perform an HTTP GET request  which will respond with status code 200 if the user is authenticated or 30x is not authenticated.
This is not ideal and if using Angular's HttpClient you can't know if a redirect has happened or not. As the browser follows the redirect under the hood and when it reaches Angular the response is a 200 of the redirected page. So you're forced to do some hacks in order to know that. Instead of being able to detect if a redirect has happened or not.
A better scenario would be to have a proper API on the backend side that returns 200 or 401/403 status code depending if the user is authenticated or not. OpenID Connect defines a UserInfo endpoint in its specs indeed for this purpose. So if your OpenID Connect provider is compliant with the spec, it should provide that endpoint.
Anyway, we all know the world's far from ideal. So in case you can't change that, you can either use one of those hacks or the new fetch API
With that, you can tell the browser not to follow redirects when performing an HTTP request from your code. Then, you can know if the request stopped due to not following redirects (user is not authenticated) or everything went good (user is authenticated).
Here's a sample code:
from(
  fetch('https://mock.httpstatus.io/302', { redirect: 'manual' }),
).subscribe((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    console.log('All went good. User is authenticated')
    return
  }
  if (!response.ok && response.type === 'opaqueredirect') {
    console.log(
      'A redirect was replied. User is probably not authenticated',
    )
    return
  }
  console.log('Something weird happened')
})


Beware that if using server side rendering (SSR) or prerendering / static site generation (SSG), you'll need fetch to be available in Node.js too. In order to run the same code on the server.
Experimental support for fetch in Node.js LTS was added in v16, though needs to be enabled via a CLI flag. From v18 onwards no CLI flag is needed. In v21 it's stable. So when v22 is LTS, it will be the first Node.js LTS to have that API as stable too. You can also use a polyfill if not running a Node.js version that supports fetch.
Angular allows to use fetch under the hood for HttpClient APIs. However not all the power of fetch has reached the HttpClient API surface yet.

